# How to store a PropertyBag class into database

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, architecture

My application is build under C# and needs dynamic properties handling. That dynamic property is handler by final user, adding and removing new fields in each of my business object.

So, my approach to that is to build a PropertyBag on every object, like:

```
public class Customer {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public PropertyBag UserProperties { get; set; }
}
```

The `PropertyBag` class we are implementing is based into this article:

[PropertyBag Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12282/Implementing-a-PropertyBag-in-C)

My question is regarding how to store that data into database for later use.

We are considering the following options:

a) Serializing the PropertyBag property into XML and storing together with the original object into a specific field.

Our thoughts is that this is easy to implement, but can add extra-extra problems to performance.

b) User a common entity-attribute-value (EAV) table to store all the object properties. Entity would be the original object, attribute the property id and value its value.

This can be tricky to implement and to maintain. Also we would have to keep all attributes as strings for better use.

c) Same approach as (b), but one EAV table for each object table.

Tricky to implement and to maintain as well, but with smaller table size.

We can´t see for now other options or alternatives. So, here goes my questions:

1. Are there other alternatives to the ones given above ?
2. Which one would be best suited for this kind of application ?

Any help appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

More information based on comment: *I think more context is needed before an answer can be derived. For example:*

*How many values will each bag have?*

Some of them may have 10 or more (20, 30 at most). Most of them will have 2-5 properties.

In total we expect to have a total of 70-100 business objects. Some of them will have 10.000 registers or more. 2 or 3 of those will have 1.000.000 records after some months.

*Do you want to be able to search the database for individual values?*

We will always look foward for searching, but our idea is to do a 2-step search. First for the "real" properties using "real" SQL filters on Db level and then using linq to filter for extended properties. This is because searching a pure EAV table will be complicated.

*Does each Customer have the same properties?*

Customers is only an example, but yes... The "extended properties" will be the same for all objects of the same business class (ex: Customers).

Comment: I think more context is needed before an answer can be derived. For example: How many values will each bag have? Do you want to be able to search the database for individual values? Does each Customer have the same properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one other option which is to add additional columns to your tables. That is probably a really bad idea for you so I won't bother discussing it.

**A. Serializing the PropertyBag property into XML**

*Pros*

1. Easy to maintain
2. Can store any number of properties

*Cons*

1. Likely to make SQL queries very awkward to write and slow.
2. Storing inside an XML datatype in SQL Server doesn't work for some ORM software
3. No referential integrity (i.e. there's nothing to stop you putting random XML in there that would break your software)

**B. Using a common entity-attribute-value (EAV) table**

*Pros*

1. You start to get some referential integrity.
2. Queries on the values are much easier to write.

*Cons*

1. A little more maintenance required.
2. Values for all your entities are coalesced into a single table which looks like it will get rather large. A conservative estimate based on your numbers, it looks like you will have 10 million property values within 3 months. Not a problem for Oracle to handle, but how about after 1 year? 2 years? Projected growth?
3. All property values would be strings. Not too complicated for text and numerics, but be careful with date/time values.
4. You can struggle to enforce some integrity on the database. For example, how do you stop assigning a property to an object it doesn't apply to?

**C. EAV table per object**

*Pros*

1. Everything from option B.
2. Much better referential integrity, now you don't need to worry about `Customer` property types being assigned to `Order` objects for example.
3. The best database performance.
4. More manageable table sizes, especially if you expect any significant growth above your 3 month estimates.

*Cons*

1. Most time to set up.
2. Lots more to maintain.

**Summary**

I've worked with option B a lot in the past and it can become a real pain. Without knowing your setup, my advice would be to go with option C. If you have the resource and are forward thinking (expecting growth, worrying up front about table sizes, indexes etc.) then this will be the choice that scales the best. It's also worth thinking now about data retention policies. For example, will you have objects that you need to delete in the future? I've yet to find a database that doesn't! So when you need to delete a bunch of `Customer` objects option B is a potential performance bottle neck.

Ultimately, only you know your requirements though, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Helps a lot.. .Thanks for the insights... By the way, We do not use ORM´s at all (architecture strategy). About the deletion, registers are "marked deleted" and then in a batch deleted in real. We are really foward thinking... Add columns would be an easy and wrong decision... Thanks for the comments.